# Infinite Loop and time

Tags: c, date, unix, infinite-loop, time.h

I'm trying to compare when does a given date corresponds to current time, when that happens it's supposed to execute a program. I have used an infinite loop so that it waits for the given time to correspond to the current time, the problem is that when that happens it executes the program more than one time and I don't know how to solve this...

```
 #include <unistd.h> 
#include <sys/wait.h> 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int taskexecution()
{   
    char * path;
    path = "/home/soraia/mieti/Proj/makefile";


    pid_t fk = fork();
    if (!fk) { /* in child */

        chdir("/home/soraia/mieti/Proj");
        execlp ("make", "make", "-f", path , NULL);

        _exit(127); 
    } 
    else if (fk == -1) 
    {    
        perror("fork"); /* print an error message */
    }
    return 0;
}

void time()
{

  struct tm  data;

  data.tm_year=2015-1900;
  data.tm_mon=1-1;
  data.tm_mday=03;
  data.tm_hour=10;
  data.tm_min=49;
  data.tm_sec=10;
  data.tm_isdst = -1;

  if(mktime(&data) == time(NULL))

   {
    taskexecution();
  }
}

int main ()
{
  while(1)
  {
    time(); 
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: *I have used an infinite loop*, then shouldn't it be expected to run in infinite time?

Comment: Yes, but when if(mktime(&data) == time(NULL)) comes it should only execute the program one time, because that condition is only true one time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the computer runs so fast that your `time()` function can be called several times in the same second. What you need is to ensure that either your function stops the while loop after having run the task, or forbids the execution of the task:

First:

```
int time()
{
  struct tm  data;   
  data.tm_year=2015-1900;
  data.tm_mon=1-1;
  data.tm_mday=03;
  data.tm_hour=10;
  data.tm_min=49;
  data.tm_sec=10;
  data.tm_isdst = -1;   
  if (mktime(&data) == time(NULL))   
   {
    taskexecution();
    return 0; // returns 0 to stop while
  }
  return 1; // returns 1 to let the while continue
}

int main ()
{
  while(time());
  return 0;
}
```

second:

```
void time()
{
  static int ran = 0; // static variable: 0 is task not already executed, 1 else
  struct tm  data;
  data.tm_year=2015-1900;
  data.tm_mon=1-1;
  data.tm_mday=03;
  data.tm_hour=10;
  data.tm_min=49;
  data.tm_sec=10;
  data.tm_isdst = -1;
  if(ran==0 && mktime(&data) == time(NULL))
   {
    taskexecution();
    ran = 1; // Ok execution took place
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I have tried the second option before but couldn't make it to work, forgot about static. Really, thank you so much!